# Why should we define "xa-datasource-class" within a driver configuration in JBoss?

Tags: java, jboss

I'm using `JBoss7AS` and have the following data-source driver definition:

```
<drivers>
  <driver name="com.mysql" module="com.mysql">
    <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
  </driver>
</drivers>
```

I'm a bit cinfused by `xa-datasource-class` subtag. Does it have something to do with transactions (E.g. JTA transactions, because they use some kind of `XA`-interfaces)? So if we delete that subtag we won't be able to use JTA-transaction in our application, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `XA` is needed by the [JTA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Transaction_API) to coordinate distributed transactions.

`XA` refers to the [X/Open XA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X/Open_XA) standard, which is a distributed transaction protocol, allowing ACID transactions to span across multiple resources which are XA compliant (this can include transactions across multiple databases of different RDBMS vendors, queues, transactional file systems, etc).

Specifically, for the config setting, from [the docs](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/Connectors_on_JBoss-Configuring_JDBC_DataSources.html):

> xa-datasource-class : The fully qualified name of the javax.sql.XADataSource implementation class, for example, com.informix.jdbcx.IfxXADataSource.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So, if we want to use distributed transaction we shall define the xa-datasource-class, shall we?

Comment: Yes. If you don't need Distributed Txns, you won't need XA  - if you only need simple transaction on a single connection to the same database. For no XA, have a [look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132785/jboss-datasource-configuration-for-mysql-mysqlxadatasource-element)